# What is this yellow diamond symbol on my map?

Tags: borderlands-2

I started playing Borderlands 2 the other day and a symbol came up on my map while doing the "Note to Self-Person" quest, where you find the stash of the goliathe in The Fridge. The symbol shows a stick-figure person like the ones you see on a bathroom door. It is in a diamond and it is yellow. What is that?

I searched the area, shot a around, tried to open things, melt ice with a flame weapon but it didn't help. I'm just baffled.

I've searched for answers to this question and came up empty handed. I have no idea what this symbol is. I've never seen it before. I have picture of it if anyone wants to see.

Comment: You can add the picture, it can't hurt. I always like to see pictures in a question or answer. Try to add it by editing your answer, and press the figure symbol (or press ctrl + G)

Comment: I'm using my phone. I'm new to this site. I'm a able to do it on my phone?

Comment: I am not sure. The mobile app is not very up-to-date for editing answers or questions. I tried editing anothing question, and there is a button (with the camera) that lets you do the same. You can choose a file from your phone, so it should work (if you have the picture on your phone)

Answer (score 2):

It's just the custom waypoint marker. If you're on pc, right click on your map to set and remove these waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

Its the custom waypoint symbol. You can add that symbol in the map.